# can I run Kiba job inside rails service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kiba-etl

Iam running kiba job from rails service that is called inside controller.
Here is current code.

```
class KibaRunner
  attr_reader :job,:logger
  def initialize(job)
    @job = job
    @logger = Rails.logger
  end
  def run
    logger.info "Running job"
    Kiba.run(kiba_job)
    true
  rescue => ex
    logger.warn ex
    false
  end

  def kiba_job
    Kiba.parse do
      source job.source.class_name, job.source.config
      destination  job.destination.class_name, job.destination.config
    end
  end
end
```

Here's what Iam getting

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `job' for #<Kiba::Context:0x00555bcd400e38>
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: inside here

 Kiba.parse do
      source job.source.class_name, job.source.config
      destination  job.destination.class_name, job.destination.config
    end

Comment: you need to use `@` notation to refer to the instance variable so in your case it should be `source @job.source.class_name, @job.source.config
      destination  @job.destination.class_name, @job.destination.config`

Comment: I have attr_reader which means job method is defined and returns @job

Comment: oh yes, missed that, what does `Kiba.parse` do or return?

Comment: `Kiba.parse` (defined [here](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/blob/master/lib/kiba/parser.rb)) evaluates the job and returns an internal `Kiba::Control` structure that you must pass to `Kiba.run`. Will reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kiba author here! Quick answer - a slightly longer stack trace with more lines & error numbers would help, but I suspect this is because the `Kiba.parse` evaluation system does not have access to the top class methods.

I suggest you pass the `job` as a method parameter, in order to make sure it is seen inside the `parse` call:

```rb
def kiba_job(job)
  Kiba.parse do
    source job.source.class_name, job.source.config
    destination  job.destination.class_name, job.destination.config
  end
end
```

Then update your service call to use this:

```rb
kiba_job(job)
```

For clarity, I'd also suggest you could rename your `job` to `job_config`.

Note that if your job takes some time, it's a good idea to run it from a background job service instead of running directly in the controller call. You can check out [this page](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/wiki/Considerations-for-running-Kiba-jobs-programmatically-%28from-Sidekiq%2C-Faktory%2C-Rake%2C-...%29) for a few recommendations on how to deal with this.

Hope this helps, let me know if this fixes it!

Comment: Great thanks - I'll take this into account for upcoming documentation updates. Thanks for asking!